# Creating a Site with 3 Virtual Directories (for ASP.NET applications)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I need to create a Site and in 3 subfolders/virtual directories for three web applications.  What I don't understand is what files should be in the Parent/Site folder?  Here is the example of the folder structure:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\applic1
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\applic2
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\applic3
```

Therefore, when I create the site (SiteName) and point to the physical folder \SiteName and there are no files there, how will it work?

Answer (score 1):

IIS will return a 403 status code and a 403 page if there are no files there. By default IIS will look for one of the following:

```
Default.html
Default.asp
index.htm
index.html
iisstart.htm
default.aspx
```

You can disable or add more files to look for if you go to the `Default document` section for the current web application in the IIS manager.

So you could leave the parent folder empty if you want to serve the default 403 page. Maybe serving some static page is nicer though.

Comment: Peco, thank you. I will try what you are suggesting.